# Maven dependency on a file not artifact

Tags: maven

Disclaimer: New to Maven and skimmed the maven documentation

How to configure Maven to look at files to determine what happens in a phase?

I am using the cxf-codegen-plugin to generate sources.  This is working correctly when I remove the .java files and execute *mvn clean generate-sources*.  However when I update the wsdl/schema that cxf uses to generate the code, the sources are not recreated.  I don't want to have to remember to delete the .java files.

Thanks for taking the time to consider my question.

Relevant excerpt from my pom is below.

```
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cxf-java</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/cxf-generated</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/DCMotor.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                        <vmArgs>
                            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                        </vmArgs>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867477/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-does-not-generate-source?rq=1 ?

Comment: I looked at that one but it works when I manually delete the generated files and the case of my tags is correct.